# Access extracted data from jsonl file

Tags: node.js, arrays, json

I'm using a chrome extension that will extract data from websites and will give me the ability to export them into jsonl format or csv.

I need to convert the exported file into an xls and I've found a good node module to achive this, my problem at the moment is the parsing of the initail jsonl file.

I'm using this code to read line by line the file

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import rl from 'readline'
import exportJSON from 'export-from-json'


const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename)

const sourceFile = path.format({
  dir: __dirname,
  base: 'sitemap.jsonl'
})

const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(sourceFile)
const readline = rl.createInterface({
  input: fileStream,
  crlfDelay: Infinity
})

let products = []

for await (const line of readline){
  products.push(line)
}
```

Since the initail format is a jsonl, I'm just pushing the data from single lines into an array. My problem is when I try to access the properties of each single object using dot notation, I've tried to loop the array and it works fine, but I'm not able to get the information I need and I'm unable then to create an xls file using the export from json library.

each line of the input file will have this structure
`{"info1":"detail", "info2":"detail", "info3": ["xys"], "info4": ["123456"]}`

How I can get the data I need??

Answer (score 1):

`readline` just returns a `string`, so your current `products` is just an array of `string`s.

If each line in the file is a valid json string, just use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the string into an object ...

```
for await (const line of readline){
  products.push(JSON.parse(line))
}
```

Then `products` will be an array of `object`s and you can do for instance

```
console.log(products[i].info1)
```

Comment: I will try and let you know. Thank you for the tip

Comment: I've tried what youv'e suggested but seems not working as expected. I will get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0` and this is caused from an url inside the json lines I have into the file. Also If I try to log the  param I need, it will give `undefined:1`

Comment: Then the respective lines in your file are not valid json ...

Comment: If I use json formatter it will tell me that the format is a valid JSON

Comment: The error while JSON parsing proves otherwise. How exactly does your file look? Add an example (not just a single line, but multiple lines) to your question.